# Android studio "design" part - no upper activity panel visible, only blank screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator

[image: The upper "TestApp" panel is not visible in my design section]

Hello,
I am having an issue in Android Studio - when designing an app, I dont see the upper panel of the app, it is only visible in the emulator, other people seem to have in their design section (Youtube,..)

Can someone help me to see the green panel in the design section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **`PreviewWindow`** -> **`View Options`** -> **`Show Layout Decorations`**

Check this red marked icon : [image: Preview Layout UI]

Comment: Thank you! Just a question, I suppose you are an advanced Android Dev, do you use this feature or not?

Comment: Not too much. Because of NoActionBar, UI looks more pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the `Show Layout Decorations` option:

**First** press the eye symbol (in android studio):

[image]

Under it, you will have a `Show Layout Decorations` option.

[image]

Just **mark it** and you will see your full preview.